# FileVault won't login

Tags: macbook-pro, filevault

The login password is entered correctly. The progress bar starts to load and gets all the way to the end, but nothing happens.

I did not turn on FileVault, just turned on my MacBook one day and this happened.

I'm using a 17" Macbook Pro.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Did you ever enable FileVault in System Preferences?

Comment: No, turn on laptop one day and needing to login to FileVault.

Comment: Restart your computer and try your Apple ID password. Sometimes, FileVault uses the same password that your iCloud account uses by default.